# ios map issue- mulitiple lines are showing on ios map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios6

Am working in ios map. Here when i draw a line on ios map using overlayer it is showing multiple lines. Now i want to draw only one straight line. How can i do this. 
Below i have attached the code with screen shot.

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([touches count]>1)
    {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    tappedPoint1 = [touch locationInView:_mapView];
//    _startCoord = [_mapView convertPoint:tappedPoint1 toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
    coord1= [_mapView convertPoint:tappedPoint1 toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
    polyline = nil;
}

   - (void)updatePolylineWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord6
{
    if (!_polyline)
    {
        MKMapPoint points[2];
        points[0] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord1);
        points[1] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord6); 
        line2 = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:2];
    }
    else
    {
        NSUInteger count = _polyline.pointCount + 1;
        // create new point array and add new coord
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[count];
        [_polyline getCoordinates:coords range:NSMakeRange(0, count-1)];
        coords[count - 1] = coord6;
        [_mapView removeOverlay:_polyline];
        line2 = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:count];
    }
    line2.title = @"line";
    [_mapView addOverlay: line2];

//    _polyline = line2;
}

        - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:_mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord5= [_mapView convertPoint:currentPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
        NSLog(@"_startCoord.latitude : %f", coord5.latitude);
        NSLog(@"_startCoord.lontitude : %f", coord5.longitude);
        [self updatePolylineWithCoordinate:coord5];
        }

        - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
        {
            if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) 
            {
                lineview=[[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];
                lineview.strokeColor=[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
                lineview.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
                lineview.lineWidth=2.0;
                return [lineview autorelease];
            }

            return nil;
        }
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
    [_mapView removeOverlay:line2];

    MKMapPoint points[2];
    points[0] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord1);
    points[1] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord5);
    line2 = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:2];
    [_mapView addOverlay: line2];
  }
```

Now when i draw a line using touch movement it is draw on everywhere on map depend on ios map. but i need when the user move his finger only one straight line will showing. how can i do this: please see this screen shot. [image]

could any body please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)updatePolylineWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord
{
    MKPolyline* line;
    if (!_polyline) {
        MKMapPoint points[2];
        points[0] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(_startCoord);
        points[1] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);        
        line = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:points count:2];
    } else {
        NSUInteger count = _polyline.pointCount + 1;
        // create new point array and add new coord
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[count];
        [_polyline getCoordinates:coords range:NSMakeRange(0, count-1)];
        coords[count - 1] = coord;
        [_mapView removeOverlay:_polyline];
        line = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:count];
    }
    line.title = @"line";
    [_mapView addOverlay: line];
    _polyline = line;


}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count]>1) {
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
        return;
    }
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint tappedPoint1 = [touch locationInView:_mapView];
    _startCoord = [_mapView convertPoint:tappedPoint1 toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];

    DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
    annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    _polyline = nil;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:_mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord= [_mapView convertPoint:currentPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
    [self updatePolylineWithCoordinate:coord];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView* lineview= [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        lineview.strokeColor=[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
        lineview.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
        lineview.lineWidth=2.0;
        return [lineview autorelease];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

You'll need to add only 2 instance variables:

- CLLocationCoordinate2D _startCoord;
- MKPolyline* _polyline;

Comment: Thanks u very much for your help.But friend sorry. now am having another issue in same code. It is magic code if am using break point for debug it is working fine. if am run the code without break point am getting the output like this:http://postimage.org/image/vnpf0vdcv/61b61049/ and also please see my editing code

Comment: @kannan I can't explain this issue but there must be a coordinate with  zero value (0,0) - maybe the variable is uninitialized. Also I can't guarantee that my code works with multiple simultaneous touches.

Comment: but am getting values in nslog

Comment: sorry for the disturbing. Ya i got the answer. But now i can draw like this:http://postimage.org/image/knfbbltj7/630881bb/. Now i want to draw only  a straight line.No need draw a circle and all. what can i do. am new to this. so only. please give me idea that is enough. please help me.

Comment: you could store the start coordinate in touchesBegan and the end coordinate in touchesEnded and then draw a polyline between these two points. you can also draw the line in touchesMoved, but always create a new polyline and remove the old one because MKPolyline is immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And also sorry for the disturb please see my edited code. it is deleting last drawn lines only so please help me what am did wrong here am struck on this issue so my project also struck here. please help me and sorry for the disturb.

Comment: @kannan Sorry, I don't want to waste my time correcting your code. I don't get paid for this...

Comment: ok sorry for disturb and wasted your time. Am extremely sorry